# Test which uses MemoryRouter to render a component requiring parameters is not working, 'unable to find role: heading'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-router

I am trying to unit test the `Profile` component which contains a `userParams()` call to get the `userID` from the path variable, to display the information for that user in a profile format.

The test uses `MemoryRouter` to route to the test with the correct parameter, and I am unsure why it is returning that it is unable to find 'role' 'heading' when there are 2 heading elements in the JSX component which should by default be given the role 'heading'.

I am unsure if the test is configured correctly, or if there is some other cause.

Fails with:

```
Unable to find role="heading"

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<body>
  <div />
</body>

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<html>
  <head />
  <body>
    <div />
  </body>
</html>
Error: Unable to find role="heading"

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

Profile.test.js

```
import React from 'react'

// import API mocking utilities from Mock Service Worker
import {rest} from 'msw'
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'

// import react-testing methods
import {render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import routeData, {MemoryRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router';

// add custom jest matchers from jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import config from "../configuration/Configuration.json";
import {Profile} from "../pages/Profile";

const userId = 1;

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get(
    config.URL + '/users/' + userId,
    (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.json({
        userId: 1,
        email: 'testEmail@outlook.com',
        password: null,
        firstName: 'Test',
        lastName: 'User'
      }))
    }
  ),
)

const renderWithRouter = ({ children }) => (
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/users/1']}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/users/:userId'>
          {children}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
)
beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())

test('loads and displays profile', async () => {
  renderWithRouter(<Profile />)

  await waitFor(
    () => screen.getByRole("heading").toHaveTextContent("Test User")
  )
})
```

Profile.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import UserService from "../services/UserService";
import {getFullName} from "../util/Util";
import '../css/profile.css';
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

export const Profile = () => { 
  //array of compatible users fetched for a user.
  const [userProfileInformation, setUserProfileInformation] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const { userId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfileInformation().then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  const getUserProfileInformation = async () => {
    const response = await UserService.getUserProfileInformation(userId)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setUserProfileInformation(data);
      });
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div id="loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="profileCard">
        <h1 name='fullName'>
          {getFullName(
            userProfileInformation.firstName, 
            userProfileInformation.lastName
          )}
        </h1>
        <h2>{userProfileInformation.email}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

I think the issue lies with your test render function `renderWithRouter`.

1. `renderWithRouter` is rendering the `children` "prop" as a child of the `Route`, but the only valid children of `Route` is another `Route` in the case of nesting routes. The `children` prop should be passed to the `Route` component's `element` prop.
2. `renderWithRouter` is a regular function, not a React component, so its argument isn't a `props` object. The test is passing `<Profile />` as an argument and `renderWithRouter` is attempting to destructure a `children` property from it. `children is OFC undefined.

## Solution

Update `renderWithRouter` to consume an `element` argument that is passed to the `Route` component's `element` prop.

```
const renderWithRouter = (element) => (
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/users/1']}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/users/:userId' element={element} />
      </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
);
```